# Fastest draw from opening position in chess

Tags: chess, optimization, checkerboard

When playing a normal game of chess, assuming the opponents are cooperating:
In how many moves can a draw be unavoidable, excluding voluntary draws or draws by repetition of moves?

1 While not capturing anything. (fastest stalemate or ..?)
2 When capturing pieces is allowed. (fastest stalemate, blockade, depletion of material or..?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1.

> From [Sam Loyd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Loyd), **12 moves.**
>     **1.** d4 e5 **2.** Qd2 e4 **3.** a4 a5 **4.** Qf4 f5 **5.** h3 Qh4 **6.** Qh2 Bb4+ **7.** Nd2 d6 **8.** Ra3 Be6 **9.** Rg3 Bb3 **10.** c4 c5 **11.** f3 f4 **12.** d5 e3 { Stalemate. }

[Try it online!](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_e5_Qd2_e4_a4_a5_Qf4_f5_h3_Qh4_Qh2_Bb4*_Nd2_d6_Ra3_Be6_Rg3_Bb3_c4_c5_f3_f4_d5_e3)

For question 2.

> Also by Sam Loyd, **9.5 moves.**
>   **1.** e3 a5 **2.** Qh5 Ra6 **3.** Qxa5 h5 **4.** Qxc7 Rah6 **5.** h4 f6 **6.** Qxd7+ Kf7 **7.** Qxb7 Qd3 **8.** Qxb8 Qh7 **9.** Qxc8 Kg6 **10.** Qe6 { Stalemate. }

[Try it online!](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e3_a5_Qh5_Ra6_Qxa5_h5_Qxc7_Rah6_h4_f6_Qxd7*_Kf7_Qxb7_Qd3_Qxb8_Qh7_Qxc8_Kg6_Qe6)

Comment: That was quick. I assume this is 'known' to be optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Even if repetition of moves is not allowed as a draw reason, I still feel this solves the puzzle. After

> 1. c3 f6 2. Qa4 Kf7 3. Qh4 Kg6 4. Qg4+ Kh6 5. Qh4+ Kg6 6. Qg4+ Kh6 7. Qh4+

Black is *forced* to do

> 7... Kg6 which leads to a threefold repetition.

So at that point, a draw is unavoidable (well, unlike stalemate, it needs to be claimed), as indicated in the question.

[Try it online!](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=c3_f6_Qa4_Kf7_Qh4_Kg6_Qg4*_Kh6_Qh4*_Kg6_Qg4*_Kh6_Qh4*)

Comment: The last move is forced, so it is sort of according to my rules, and iirc. if you repeat twice more it is even a draw without claiming. So, nice solution , but not what I intended.